# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE update with new values

Tags: mysql

I have simple table onupdate with two columns: ID and Content and one record: [1, 'old content'].
I want to replace content with new content when adding a record [1, 'new content']. Is it possible to do with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE syntax? By doing in this way the old value remains:

```
INSERT INTO onupdate (id, content) VALUES (1, 'newcontnet')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  onupdate.content = onupdate.content
```

The the example is for illustration purposes only. Please don't propose UPDATE query since I don't know if ID exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT
INTO    onupdate
        (id, content)
VALUES  (1, 'newcontnet')
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE  content = VALUES(content)
```

`VALUES(content)` means "value that would be there if `INSERT` took place"

Answer (score 3):

Saying `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE onupdate.content = onupdate.content` is like saying "If `id` is already there, take `content` and replace it with itself". You presumably want to put your new data in its place:

```
INSERT INTO onupdate (id, content) VALUES (1, 'newcontnet')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  onupdate.content = 'newcontnet'
```